# Compare two Dataframe columns and retrive the mismatched columns in a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, compare

I am trying to compare two dataframes and create one column in the first dataframe says that mismatched columns. attaching the Dataframe images and expected output images below. Could I get some help here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svSPz.png)
attaching the expected outputs here.Need one column says that names of all mismatched columns

Comment: please update your question with reproducible inputs (as **text**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming aligned indices, you can use:

```
df1['mismatch'] = df1.ne(df2).dot(df1.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

Alternatively:

```
out = (df1.ne(df2).reset_index().melt('index')
       .query('value').groupby('index')
       ['variable'].agg(','.join)
      )

df1['mismatch'] = out
```

Example output:

```
   A  B  C mismatch
0  1  2  3      A,B
1  4  5  6        A
2  7  8  9
```

Used inputs:

```
# df1
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

# df2
   A  B  C
0  0  0  3
1  0  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: Perfect it is working .Thanks so much
One more quick query the comparison is not picking for column data type as Date
could you please help me on that as well

Comment: @SujithM we would need a reproducible example (as DataFrame constructor)

Comment: Yes sorry for adding image on my above comment
attaching the image below. Could you please help me on that

Comment: I don't see your image, but anyway don't use images of data, provide reproducible text as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74729394/edit) to your question.

Comment: Any reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: accepted mozway. It is working as expected now thank you so much

Comment: so, what was the change?

Comment: I have updated the data frame by replacing null values with todays date and then kt got fixed. Thank you for your great help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Applying two lambda loops first to check if cell values equal or not second to find out the column names with true value and join them.
Alternatively, instead of second lambda, You can even use `.dot()`. as  @mozway  has done.

Code:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x!=df2.iloc[x.index][x.name]).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index[x]), axis=1)
```